# Asymptotics of two expressions involving logarithms

Tags: asymptotics, logarithms

***(As I am new to algorithmic complexity so),***[image]

**EDIT:**

[image]

please give solutions for large x (means as x->infinity) !

Comment: I didn't realize you didn't use LaTeX. You might want to learn how to use it because it is inbuilt here, where you enclose a LaTeX formula in a pair of dollar signs. You can click on "Edit" under any existing question or answer to see the code they use for their LaTeX. Just don't click "Save".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use backslash for special functions like $\ln$.

You didn't specify whether $x \to 0$ or $x \to \infty$ or something else, so your question is not precise enough. But either way, the technique is always to look for the most significant term and "pull it out" in some way to get to some form with an asymptotic expansion. For example:

$\ln(x+1) - \ln(x-1) \\
 = \ln(x(1+\frac{1}{x})) - \ln(x(1-\frac{1}{x})) \\
 = ( \ln(x) + \ln(1+\frac{1}{x}) ) - ( \ln(x) + \ln(1-\frac{1}{x}) ) \\
 \approx ( \frac{1}{x} ) - ( - \frac{1}{x} ) \text{ as } x \to \infty \\
 = \frac{2}{x}$

The asymptotic expansion used here is the Taylor series.

[Edit: Now that the question has been clarified..]

Use the same technique, since the outer function is increasing, we need to identify the asymptotically greatest term inside and factor it out:

$\ln(\frac{\ln(x)+1}{\ln(x)^3}) \\
 = \ln(\frac{1}{\ln(x)^2}(...)) \\
 = -\ln(\ln(x)^2) + \ln(...) \\
 \approx -\ln(\ln(x)^2) + ... \text{ as } x \to \infty$

again using the Taylor series.

Comment: It's completely relevant, as LutzL's answer uses exactly the same technique. In general this method is probably applicable to almost all such "simple" formulae that use only elementary functions and no induction.

Comment: By the way, avoid saying "solutions for large $x$", because Big-O denotes the behaviour as $x$ tends to something, and doesn't mean anything for fixed $x$. Also, "greater" might suggest ">" where sign is important, in which case we can simply observe that one is positive and the other negative. This is just to be more precise, since we know that you mean "asymptotically larger" of course.

Comment: If you think my answer is helpful, do upvote it. Also, please be careful in your notation. $\ln(x)^2$ is not the same as $\ln(x^2)$. But guessing what you mean, your try in your edit is correct if you find the correct value of $c$. Note that Big-O is sensitive to constants in exponents, so other values of $c$ will be incorrect.

Comment: its same what I wrote ie.; ln (x)^2 also if f(x)=e^O(g(x)) then can it be interpreted as f(x)=O(e^(g(x))) ?

Comment: No you wrote $clnlnx^2$ which would normally be interpreted as $c\ln(\ln(x^2))$ but you clearly meant $c\ln(\ln(x)^2)$ since that was the previous question's answer.

Comment: To your last question, no. It is best to think of anything involving asymptotic notation as a class of functions. (And I don't know why standard texts abuse notation by using equal signs.) So $e^{O(g)} = \{ e^h : h \in O(g) \}$ for any function $g$. This includes functions like $h : x \mapsto e^{2g(x)}$. On the other hand $O(e^g) = \{ h : \limsup_{x\to\infty} \left|\frac{h}{e^g}\right| < \infty \}$ for any function $g$. If $g(x)=x$, does $h$ belong to this class?

Answer (score 2):

You can subtitute $y=\ln x$ and apply logarithm laws,

$$\ln\left(\frac{y+1}{y^3}\right)=\ln\left(1+\tfrac1y\right)-2\ln(y)=O(1/y)+O(\ln(y)),$$ 
which is both smaller or contained in $O(y^{\frac12})$

---

After the Edit: first simplify your expression. Then it reads as

$$x\cdot\frac{0.2}{y}\cdot\frac{y+1}{y^3}$$

which is $O(x\ln(x)^{-3})$ which is contained in $o(x)$.

Comment: Thanks but please see my edit !